# Series $1$, $1$, $\frac12$, $\frac12$, $\frac13$, $\frac13$, etc.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analyticity

Is there any way to define an analytical function in a region that's contained by 0 and 1 that will correspond with the following series:

$1$, $1$, $\frac12$, $\frac12$, $\frac13$, $\frac13$, $\dots$, $\frac{1}{n}$, $\frac{1}{n}$

(such that $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1, f(3) = \frac12, f(4) = \frac12, \dots$)?

I've tried using some combinations of exponents and $\sin$ but couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)?

Comment: f(k) = 1 / floor((k + 1)/2). Right?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you explain what you mean by "that's contained by $0$ and $1$? Do you want the range of $f$ to be between $0$ and $1$ or its domain or do you want $0$ and $1$ to be contained in one of these two? And by analytic you mean that there exists a converging Taylor series of $f$ at every point of its domain?

Comment: @Hrodelbert: 0 and 1 contained in the domain

Comment: @L16H7: With that, I can't prove it's analytical

Comment: Try Fourier series. It will give a wave-like function.

Comment: are you looking for complex function ?